# No template specified for component in Angular 8/9

Tags: angular, typescript

I get this error message after I updated from Angular 8 to Angular 9:

> Error: error TS100: No template specified for component AddressTypeCreateEditComponent

In Angular 8 got this error if I tried to build in production mode, but it wasn't neccessary in this case right now. But now I updated and the update's migration process get this error again.

Here is the AddressTypeCreateEditComponent:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractCreateEditComponent } from 'src/app/components/_absrtact/create-edit/abstract-create-edit.component';
import { AddressTypeInterface } from 'src/app/models/address/type/address-type.interface';
import { AddressType } from 'src/app/models/address/type/address-type.model';
// this is a .ts file
import template from 'src/app/components/_absrtact/create-edit/abstract-create-edit.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-type-create-edit',
  template: template as string,
})
export class AddressTypeCreateEditComponent extends
    AbstractCreateEditComponent<AddressTypeInterface>
    implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    super(AddressType);
  }

}
```

Here is the abstract-create-edit.component.html.ts:

```js
export default `<div class="container-fluid">...</div>`;
```

Comment: Why putting the html in a ts file?

Comment: Wondering why you get errors i tried it with angular 9 rc1 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-r25csk and it works

Answer (score 4):

Create a address-type-create-edit.html and put the html inside of it
then change

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-type-create-edit',
  template: template as string,
})
```

to

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-type-create-edit',
  templateUrl: './address-type-create-edit.html',
})
```

Comment: not a good idea, because I want to use the `abstract-create-edit.component.html` instead of `address-type-create-edit.html` and I want to avoid this path `../../../../../_abstract/list/abstract-create-edit.component.html`

Comment: but the if I try to use this: `src/app/components/_abstract/list/abstract-list.component.html` then I get `ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve src/app/components/_abstract/list/abstract-list.component.html in ...` error message